# Given a table of private messages, how do I find my n most-recent contacts?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table of private messages that looks like this:

```
create_table "messages" do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.integer  "sender_id"    # corresponds to a user_id
  t.integer  "recipient_id" # corresponds to a user_id
end
```

I need a method for finding the n most-recent contacts for a given user. E.g., if I receive these messages in order:

0) stu
1) ariel
2) ariel
3) ariel
4) dan
5) dan
6) todd
7) ilan

My 3 most-recent contacts are ilan, todd, and dan. My 4 most-recent contacts are ilan, todd, dan, and ariel, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Assuming you have following models:

```
class User
  has_many :received_messages, :class_name=> "Message", 
             :foreign_key => :recipient_id
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name=> "Message", 
             :foreign_key => :sender_id

  def recently_active_contacts(kount=5)
    received_messages.
      select(:recipient_id).
      include(:recipient).
      group(:recipient_id).
      order("MAX(messages.created_at) DESC").
      limit(kount).
      map(&:recipient)
  end
end

class Message
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name=> "User", :foreign_key => :sender_id
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name=> "User", :foreign_key => :recipient_id
end
```

You can do the following:

```
user.recently_active_contacts
user.recently_active_contacts(3)
```

Comment: QUESTION: what if I want the same thing, but for users who have EITHER sent OR received emails to / from me. When I try `GROUP BY recipient_id, sender_id`, I get duplicate results (e.g., stuff like `[#<Message sender_id: 7, recipient_id: 1>, #<Message sender_id: 1, recipient_id: 7>]`)

Answer (score 1):

I can't "translate" to Ruby-on-Rails, but here's the SQL:

```
SELECT sender_id
FROM messages
WHERE recipient_id = @current_user_id
GROUP BY sender_id
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC
```

I guess you have a `created_at` field that stores the order of received messages.

Comment: QUESTION: what if I want the same thing, but for users who have EITHER sent OR received emails to / from me. When I try `GROUP BY recipient_id, sender_id`, I get duplicate results (e.g., stuff like `[#<Message sender_id: 7, recipient_id: 1>, #<Message sender_id: 1, recipient_id: 7>]`)